# Create a for loop inside the create firebase collection function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am creating a food app with Ionic (4) /Angular which can handle severals stores and which use FireBase. But I have a problem. I create a new order like so

```
add(stores: Array<CartStore>, address: string) {
 this.afs.collection<Order>('orders').add({
          userId: this.userId,
          address: address,
          items: stores.items,
          store: {
            id: stores.id,
           name: stores.name,
          }
        });     
      }
```

To create ONE SINGLE order, I need to use a for loop like so inside the function above

```
 for(let i in stores){
items: stores[i].items,
          store: {
            id: stores[i].id,
           name: stores[i].name,
          }
}
```

But this is impossible inside the firebase collection function... Arghhh!

Then,

This is how my app works :

By clicking on the checkout button

```
this.orderProvider.add(this.cart.stores, this.address);
```

My models:

Cart.ts

```
import { CartStore } from "./cart-store";

export class Cart {
  id?: string;
  userId: string;
  total: number;
  stores: Array<CartStore>;
}
```

Order.ts

```
import { CartStore } from "./cart-store";

export class Order {
  id?: string;
  userId: string;
  total?: number;
  address: string;
  status?: string;
  orderNumber?: string;
  createdAt?: number;
  updatedAt?: number;
  store: CartStore;
  items: Array<CartStore>;
  isReviewed?: boolean;
}
```

Cart-Store.ts

```
import { CartItem } from './cart-item';

export class CartStore {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  subTotal?: number;
  items?: Array<CartItem>;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Cart-Item.ts

```
import { Variation } from "./variation";
import { ItemReview } from "./item-review";
import { Size } from "./size";

export class CartItem {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  quantity: number;
  thumbnail: string;
  variations: Array<Variation>;
  size: Size;
  subTotal: number;
  review?: ItemReview;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Thank you for helping me! I am beginning in this domain.

Comment: If you always only have one store you can access it directly like stores[0].items, etc.

Otherwise, loop over stores before the collection.add() call to add an order for each store.

Comment: stores[0] does not work because it not refer to a specific store. I put all the code you need, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for of loop:

```
add(stores: Array<CartStore>, address: string) {
    for (const store of stores) {
      if (store && store.items && store.items.length) {
        this.afs.collection<Order>('orders').add({
          userId: this.userId,
          address: address,
          items: store.items,
          store: {
            id: store.id,
            name: store.name
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: By doing this with ordering 2 items, it created 17 orders and 2 of them have each one item .

Comment: The 15 others orders does not have any item.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this

```
add(stores: Array<CartStore>, address: string) {
    for (let i in stores) {
      if (stores[i] && stores[i].items && stores[i].items.length) {
        this.afs.collection<Order>('orders').add({
          userId: this.userId,
          address: address,
          items: stores[i].items,
          store: {
            id: stores[i].id,
            name: stores[i].name
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

But this create severals order (for each items) instead of create one single order with all items.

Comment: If you want to create all items in one order you should iterate over the items beforehand and create your object with the correct structure, so you can only add this object in one add call.

Comment: since you are checking for stores[i].items.length already, it should only add orders which actually also have items. Could you please post an example data structure? I.e. what is passed as stores to add function

Comment: I just uploaded something.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not help. 
I was asking for the input you pass to your add(stores: Array<CartStore>, address: string) method.

You can add a console.log(stores) before your for loop and please post the output here.

Comment: Replace your for in loop by a for of loop.

For in is used for objects while for of is used for arrays :)

Comment: It does not work :'( . It created an order for each item.

Comment: Do you have any solution else for this problem ?

Comment: This should work, if you can share a jsfiddle or stackblitz I can help you!

Comment: I don't use jsfiddle or stackblitz.

Comment: This does not work because 'store' (after the if condition which is used as a filter for useless 'store' array) stock one item only.

Comment: Each item is stocked in a different 'store'.

Comment: Do you have any other solution please ?

Comment: This is what i was talking about in my very first comment here: If you want to create all items in one order you should iterate over the items beforehand and create your object with the correct structure, so you can only add this object in one add call.

If you can share your example in a stackblitz i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my store.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Store } from '../models/store';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StoreService {

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {

  }

  all() {
    return this.afs.collection<Store>('stores/').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Store;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return {id, ...data};
      });
    }));
  }

  get(id: string) {
    return this.afs.doc('stores/' + id).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

And this is my store.ts

```
export class Store {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  itemCount?: number;
  rateCount?: number;
  rating?: number;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

I have 2 apps which are linked to the same firebase, one is for the customers, the other is for the admins (store account). I notice that I have only one admin account in firebase.